# What is the 'not equal to' selector in Qt stylesheets?

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qtstylesheets

The title said it all. Is there any style-sheet selector to select a widget that have properties not equal to a value?
Something like following:

```
QPushButton["something"!="xxx"] { background: red; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no, there's no such selector available, according to what is said [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types):

> Qt Style Sheets support all the selectors defined in CSS2.

and what is [documented](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors) in CSS2.

Comment: Thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

A workaround could be to set some values for every instance and change them after for the specific case you want (if you can explicitly set the default value) :

```
QPushButton { background: red; }
QPushButton["something"=="xxx"] { background: /* Your default color */;  }
```